# Selenium tool is not able to identify the element by xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the naukri.com application.

After the successful login I need to search the jobs based on the skills, location, experience and salary.With the help of xpath I was able to identify the first element(Skills, Designation, companies).Below is the xpath code for the same

`//div[@id='skill']`

However, when I run the script, the element is not identified and the script fails.And just to add the element doesn't fall in any frame.Please kindly help me to resolve the issue and screen print attached for reference[image]

--Here is the code for reference--

```
public class naukri {
@Test
public void pagelaunch() throws InterruptedException
 {
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("http://www.naukri.com");
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
 //close all the pop ups
 Set<String> pops=driver.getWindowHandles();
 {
 Iterator<String> it =pops.iterator();
 while (it.hasNext()) {

     String popupHandle=it.next().toString();
     if(!popupHandle.contains(parent))
     {
     driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
     System.out.println("Pop Up Title: "+                                                                                   driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle).getTitle());
     driver.close();
     }
 }
 }
 driver.switchTo().window(parent);

 //to click on login button and proceed to login to the application
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Jobseeker Login']")).click();

    for (String winhandle:driver.getWindowHandles())
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(winhandle);

    }


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='uSel']")).click();
             driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='uLogin']")).sendKeys("anand_qa");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pLogin']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pLogin']")).sendKeys("test@1234");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='blueBtn']")).click();
     driver.switchTo().window(parent);

     Thread.sleep(5000);
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Search Jobs']"));
     Actions action = new Actions(driver);
     action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Jobs by Skill']")).click();
     Thread.sleep(5000);

     List<String> browserTabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

     driver.switchTo().window(browserTabs.get(1));
     //Below are the two elements which are not identified by the tool but the same gets identified thru fire bug 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='skill']")).sendKeys("testing");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='location']")).sendKeys("bangalore");

}
```

Comment: Please add the code of the script where you try to locate the element from Selenium.

Comment: You need to add relevant HTML, part of script and stacktrace. Otherwise it is difficult to see the problem

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver");
WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) cls.newInstance();
driver.get("http://naukri.com");
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='skill']"));
System.out.println(webElement.isEnabled());
```

Output is:

> true